# Populate a recyclerview with a SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I wish to populate my recyclerview with my SQLite database but I am unsure how to do so. I am stuck and unsure how to do so. I believe it has something to do with adapter but again I am not sure.

If you need to see and additional code like my SQLite class or the recyclerview activity please don't hesitate to ask.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class SQLite_RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SQLite_RecyclerViewAdapter.VHItem> {
List<SQLite_Information> data = Collections.emptyList();



public SQLite_RecyclerViewAdapter(Sqlite_activity sqlite_activity, List<SQLite_Information> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public VHItem onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new VHItem(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_sqlite_row, parent, false));    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(VHItem holder, int position) {
    SQLite_Information sqLite_information = data.get(position);
    holder.Score.setText(sqLite_information.mScore);
    holder.Date.setText(sqLite_information.mDate);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView Score;
    TextView Date;

  public VHItem(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Score = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ScoreText);
        Date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.DateText);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: `SQLiteDatabase` has various query methods that return a `Cursor`.  A `Cursor` can be used to make a `CursorAdapter`.  So one approach might be to wrap the `CursorAdapter` with a `RecyclerView.Adapter` and delegate to the `CursorAdapter`.  This would be appropriate especially if you read your data once and the `ListView` does not have to be notified about data modified by refresh queries.

If you don't know about `CursorLoader`, look into how that works.  That is the best way to get `Cursor`s from queries, since the `CursorLoader` takes care of running all the database queries in the background.  When the `CursorLoader` completes, take the resulting `Cursor` and create the `CursorAdapter`, then take that and create your `RecyclerView.Adapter` subclass.